# VirtualBox Very Slow Boot Time

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have a VirtualBox machine running Lubuntu 15.04 with an excessively slow boot time (1:30+). It does not have the VirtualBox guest additions installed.

The problem started when I had completely run out of virtual space on the VM. I used `VBoxManage <VDI file> --resize <10 GB>` to resize the disk, and then used a gparted live cd to reconfigure the partitions. I set it up such that there were only two partitions(`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` respectively), with the first being an `ext4` filesystem, and the second being a 1GiB `linux-swap` partition.

After that, the VM would boot correctly, but very slow.

[image: This image shows a message with some timer.]

The problem is that it is waiting for the timer to hit 1:30 to continue booting.

What does the message mean and how do I fix it?

---

For future readers:
I solved this problem by running the below procedures:

1. `sudo mkswap /dev/sda2` (this outputs a new UUID)
2. `sudo swapon /dev/sda2`
3. `sudo leafpad /etc/fstab`

   - Replace the swap UUID with the new one
4. `sudo update-grub` (ensure no old UUIDs are laying around)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some googling I have found [this forum thread about similar problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201816). The solution proposed is to format swap partition:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sdXY
sudo mkswap /dev/sdXY
sudo swapon /dev/sdXY
```

(substitute `sdXY` with your swap partition name, eg. `sda2`)

Comment: **Thank you!** This didn't work perfectly, but I managed to get it to work.